# JQuery Popup Window/Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After looking at 50 different JQuery Menu/popup plugins, I have yet to find what I'm looking for.

I'd like to build popup-window that behaves much like a popup menu but has a lot of custom formatted links, images, text, etc. in it.  So something that's based purely on ul and li isn't really going to work.

In fact, all I really need is the ability to popup a window (non-modal, and will hide when a user clicks elsewhere on the screen), just below a link and treat it as just a DIV with some custom layout.  Something like what LinkedIn has going on with their menu in this screen shot:
[image]

Any suggestions on 1) existing plugins or 2) how to approach myself...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) one.
There are so many, that one should fit for your needs

Comment: There were actually a couple demos in that page that I haven't seen before.  Some useful stuff for me to chew on.

Comment: Marked this one as the answer since there was a sample on the linked to page that I was easily able to use as my base.  THanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample5) and made a menu like this:
[image]

my html looks like this:

```
    <a href="product"><span>Produkter</span></a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/produkter/mdoc"><img src="/media/1556/Crop_video_menu1.png" alt="Product" />
<span class="megaMenuContent"><span>Mdoc</span><br />
<span>
    Kontaktdatabase (Mdoc dokumenttype)<br />
    Office og mail integration<br />
    Brugervenlighed<br />    
    <br /></span>
</span></a></li></ul>
```

i use span because div is not valid within a li

Comment: You can put enything within the span it is just an eksample... you can even add divs but the page wont be w3 valid then

Answer (score 0):

Id say build it as a DIV like you mentioned and use jquery/css for positioning and open/close functions.

I dont think there is a plugin that will net exactly what your requirements are.